# Filtering time periods where relationship is swiched on/off

Tags: time-series, change-point, structural-change

Sorry for the "unmathematical" formulation of the problem to come, but I am not sure where to place my problem:

Suppose there exists a relationship between the variables x and y. I can observe both variables over time.
However, this relationship is switched off at certain times and later switched on. E.g. people behave rational in some times, leading to x causing y and in other times they behave irrational and y becomes random.

So, when I run the time series regression y ~ x + 1, I will find no significant x due to the switched-off periods. When I "pick" the right period, however, I do.

My question: How would I formulate my problem in the language of statistics and is there any way to filter the times where the relationship hold?

Comment: Brute forcing the problem would be estimating the $n^2$ regressions: $y_t = \beta x_t * p_t + \epsilon_t$ with the vector $p_t$ taking all possible combinations of 0 and 1 and pick the best one, right ($*$ is pice-wise multiplication)? The picked $p_t$ would give me the time periods...

Comment: Do you know when the switches occur, or not? if not, this sounds like a Markov regime-switching model might be useful.

Comment: Whatever you do, beware of cherry picking and validate your method by showing that it does not find any result for appropriate random data (without any correlations).

Comment: No, I don't know the times. And the "cherry picking" thing is exactly why I am looking for a method to estimate the times. Because, when I pick the periods by hand, I will always find those where my model works...

Comment: Following up the regime-switching brought up by Glen, I found this paper: http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~cocteau/stat204/readings/quandt.pdf which seems to be just the problem (however reduced to one switching point). So, the formulation part of my question seems to be solved.